# JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, cookies, hide, visibility, hidden

I am building this small cookiescript which creates a cookie when clicking on a button and then hides the message.

But now I am building the function to hide the message (div#cookie) when the cookie has been seet, but I get this error everytime, but my div DOES exist:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Now these are the scripts I am using, can anyone help? :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }

        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        function eraseCookie(name) {
            createCookie(name,"",-1);
        }
        </script>
```

and this, where-ever the 'hidediv' gives the error, but does work when clicking on a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function hidediv() { 
                if (document.getElementById) { 
                    document.getElementById('cookie').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                    createCookie('uscnCookieScriptJS','uscninternetservicescookiescriptjavascriptversion',365)

                } 
                else { 
                    if (document.layers) { 
                        document.hideShow.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                        createCookie('uscnCookieScriptJS','uscninternetservicescookiescriptjavascriptversion',356)
                    } 
                    else { 
                        document.all.hideShow.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                        createCookie('uscnCookieScriptJS','uscninternetservicescookiescriptjavascriptversion',356)
                    } 
                } 
            }

            function showdiv() { 
                if (document.getElementById) { 
                    document.getElementById('cookie').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                } 
                else { 
                    if (document.layers) { 
                        document.hideShow.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    } 
                    else { 
                        document.all.hideShow.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("uscnCookieScriptJS") >= 0) {
          alert("yes");
          hidediv();
        }
        else {
          alert("no");
        }
        </script>
```

The script can be found here: http://dev.uscn.nl/cookiescript/v2/

Comment: You have no element hideShow in the HTML, but this should lead the error only in browsers that do not support getElementById

Comment: browsers that don't support getElementById (srsly?) would just throw an error that getElementById is not a function or similar. You wouldn't see style is null or whatever.

Comment: maybe, The problem is that you are calling the javascript function before loading the actual HTML content..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `hidediv()` function before loading the actual HTML content. Either put the script in the end of the document (before closing `body` tag) or set it at `window.onload` / on document ready